# Google glass- GDK- Unable to inflate view from XML file

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I am running glass XE 19.1,I am trying to use layout inflator the XML file does exist under layouts folder but the file is never recognized.

> card_countdown cannot be resolved is the error I get.

```
public CountDownView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs,
                final int style) {
            super(context, attrs, style);
            LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.card_countdown, this);

            this.mSecondsView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.seconds_view);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure where your method is called but if you are using a live card you should add item Stop to your menu